# Where do PHP Composer Packages Come From?

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run

```
$ composer.phar install
```

where do the packages that get installed come from?

I understand that [Packagist](https://packagist.org) is the default repository for  PHP packages, and that lacking a different package in `composer.json`, this is where composer will look for packages.

However, what I'm not clear on is how Composer and Packagist interact.

- Does Composer download files directly from `packagist.org`
- Or does Composer get a git/svn/hg repository link from `packagist` and download the files from the repository directly?
- Or something else?

Comment: packagist holds links to the repositories, and that's where they're downloaded from

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on the contents of your `composer.json` file.

For example, if your `composer.json` contained simply

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.8.*@dev"
    }
}
```

then composer searches packagist, and finds phpunit here:

https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit

which tells composer to load phpunit from here:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git

If instead your `composer.json` contained

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.8.*@dev"
    }
}
```

then composer will not look to packagist, but go directly to github to download the repo.

The packages registered on Packagist are *usually* the "authoritative" version of the package (not a fork), but I have found several instances where this is *NOT* the case, so you should check it to be sure you are pulling the package you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Packagist.org offers users to register their software there by pointing Packagist to read their composer.json file that is published somewhere on the web.

The usual case would be some of the common open source hosters like github, which makes it really easy because composer can deal with such a git repo right away. You could however host your own git or svn or hg repository, or even just publish ready-made ZIP or TGZ files for each software version.

Composer downloads directly from the source, e.g. Packagist only knows those source and tells your composer instance where to go. It does this by downloading a bunch of json files from Packagist.org that have all the infos. This is way easier than to find out where the libraries that you want are hosted and add this info as a repository entry into your local composer.json file. :)